# Stop client to create WCF proxy at his end from VS IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, proxy

suppose i have developed a web service and i want to distribute the proxy class to client and then client can add that proxy class to their project to make call of my service but if client some how know the url of my wcf service then he/she will not be able to create proxy classes by adding reference from VS IDE.

just tell me what are the area i need to disable in my service?

if i remove mex endpoint & httpgeturl = false then will it sufficient ? or anything extra i need to configure ?

i consumed one wcf service where company just give me the wsdl & proxy classes. from wsdl i got the service url but when i try to add that service url as add reference from VS IDE then windows auth login diolog comes. so i could not create proxy from VS ide then i just add their proxy related .cs files to my project and had to call the service.

so i like to know how could prevent or stop the client as a result if they know my wcf service url they will not be able to create proxy classes from their VS IDE from adding service reference. please guide in detail. thanks

Comment: The logon dialog most likely came up  because there was was auth enabled on the binding

Comment: @Dhawalk : not very clear what u try to say.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"** node from web.config.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour" >

                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```